# Get instruction by address with IDAPython

Tags: idapython

I want to get an instruction with IDAPython by address of this instruction.

For example from `mov r0 r1` I want to get only `mov`.

How can I do that with IDAPython?

Answer (score 1):

To get the full disassembly, you can use:

```
GetDisasm(<address_of_instruction>)
```

To get the instruction only, you can use:

```
ida_ua.ua_mnem(<address_of_instruction>)
```

Comment: I need only the instruction. For example from `mov r0 r1` O want to get only `mov`

Comment: Added to the answer

Comment: Thanks. And how can I get the `r0` and `r1` please?

Comment: @Python, it's not fair to ask additional questions, moreover if you even didn't appreciate the right answer by accepting it and/or voting it up.